# Is the = Operator More Efficient than the IN operator T-SQL

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I've recently been researching the most efficient way to write my queries in order to streamline an application I'm designing. One of my co-workers mentioned that I should use = when possible instead of IN () because using IN is slower than using =. However, I have not been able to find any sources to support this.

Does anyone here know whether this is true of false? And if so, do you happen to know why?

So that you have some code to see what I'm asking, this is an example of what I'm asking.

Is this :

```
SELECT [Some Columns]... FROM db.dbo.table WHERE [this column] = 'Something'
```

More efficient than this :

```
SELECT [Some Columns]... FROM db.dbo.table WHERE [this column] IN ('Something' )
```

Comment: It will be the same. Optimizer will generate equal plans

Comment: Write readable code. optimize only if necessary. beware of the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2):

If this was the case SQL Server would perform this (trivial) rewrite for you. It is not the case. The capabilities of the optimizer are far beyond such trivial rewrites.

Your coworker has superstitious beliefs about SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

That actually depends on your query.Lets say column IN (1,2,3) is like you are searching for column =1 OR column = 2 OR column =3.If you have index its upto you to use IN operator OR = operator.I would normally prefer USING '=' operator for single value 'IN' operator for multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two in SMSS and then show query plan.  I will show the same plan for each and each as 50% of the total cost.  That would be the easiest way to  prove to your co-worker.

There are some syntax that can be more efficient like exists over an in but this is not one of the cases.